# How to get WhatsApp contact name in Twilio Studio flow

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I want to obtain the whatsapp name from an incoming message to send the info to flex, i saw an old post and twilio recieves the info in the key ProfileName, but in twilio studio logs i dont see the attribute ProfileName.

Anyone has an idea about this?